# How can I add file two different file into two different repository?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

for ex: I have two file a.py and b.py, then I want add a.py in xyz  and b.py in abc repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but using a single project, I would assume? You add two remote to your project, create two branches, one for each remote... checkout one of those branches, add a.py, commit, push to its remote. Checkout the other branch, add b.py, commit, push to the other remote.

Comment: I don't see any error message on the question. Can you add the output of the command you tried and the output?